# More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression (without sub-query)

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to execute PostgreSQL query as below:

```
SELECT y.a, y.b, y.c, y.d, y.e, y.f, y.g, x.h, x.i, x.j, x.k 
FROM y 
  JOIN x x ON y.b = x.b 
WHERE UPPER(USERNAME) ILIKE 'USER1'
```

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

There is no subquery in this, yet it gives above error.

What could be the issue? How to fix it?

Comment: Is this the actual query, and if not can you include that?

Comment: is `x` or `y` a view?

Comment: If there's *really* no subquery in the *real* query, are you using views, where one of the views might be generating the error?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes they are view.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Due to confidentiality, I have just replaced names (i.e X, Y etc) otherwise Query is exactly same.

Comment: Then the problem is in the views, not in the query you are using

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you are right, I can't even query my VIEW, thanks a lot :)